# Update existing subscription with incomplete state (3D Secure)

Tags: stripe-payments, subscription

With normal payment without subscription update here are the steps I follow :

1. Create subscription (server side)
2. Check `subscription.latest_invoice.payment_intent.status === "requires_action"`
3. Send `subscription.latest_invoice.payment_intent.client_secret` to the client
4. Call `confirmCardPayment` using the `payment_intent_secret`

But when updating the subscription I don't want to have the subscription in `incomplete` state because it will overwrite the existing subscription because of the `subscription.update` call.

But I do need to retrieve the payment_intent from the subscription but without overwriting.
I tried different `payment_behavior` values, the `error_if_incomplete` does not create the subscription but I cannot retrieve the payment_intent.

The `allow_incomplete` do have a payment intent but it overwrite the existing subscription on stripe side.

I'm not sure what's the correct way of updating plan with 3D secure.

Comment: If you wish to only update the subscription to new plan after a successful payment, you can use pending update feature here: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/pending-updates